# Find the multiplicative order of $15$ mod $ 257$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

could someone please help me with this problem?  Thanks in advance!

Find the multiplicative order of $15$ modulo $257$.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show us what you have tried so far. Hint. Do you know why the answer must be a power of $2$? You can do the repeated squaring a step at a time. (This is for the multiplicative order.)

Comment: Do you want to find the additive order or the multiplicative order? You can do both of course, as $257$ is a prime number. The additive order is then simply $257$.

Comment: @RMWGNE96 Multiplicative.

Answer (score 2):

$$15^2\equiv-2^5\pmod{257}$$

Now $2^8\equiv-1\pmod{257}$

$\implies$ord$_{257}2=16$

$\implies$ord$_{257}2^5=\dfrac{16}{(16,5)}=16$

$\implies$ order of $-2^5$ modulo $257$ will be $16$ as for $(-2^5)^{2m}=(2^5)^{2m}$ for any integer $m$

$\implies$ord$_{257}15=2\cdot16$

Comment: At this level one should justify the 1st,2nd & last arrows  (likely the OP doesn't know the 2nd, and possibly also the 1st & last)

Answer (score 1):

Since the order is divisible into $257-1=256=2^8$, it must be a power of $2$.  Find this by squaring until you hit $1$:

$15^2\equiv 225\equiv -32$

$15^4\equiv 32^2\equiv 1024\equiv -4$

$15^8\equiv 4^2\equiv 16$

and after two more squarings you get $15^{\color{blue}{32}}\equiv 1$.

Answer (score 0):

$15$ has the same order $\pmod {257}$ as its inverse $120.$

$120^2=14400\equiv8\pmod{257}$.

Therefore $120^6\equiv8^3=512=2\times256=2\times(257-1)\equiv-2 \pmod {257}.$

Therefore $120^{12}\equiv(-2)^2=4\pmod{257}$.

Therefore $120^{16}=120^{12}(120^2)^2\equiv 4\times8^2=256\equiv-1\pmod{257}.$

Therefore the order of $120$ (and hence $15$) modulo $257$ is $32$.

Comment: Why choose the power sequence $\, 2\to 6\to 12\to 16\,$ vs. repeated squaring? That seems to imply you already know the order and and are *verifying* it (vs. *discovering* it), e.g. if the order was $8$ then you would have missed it using that sequence of powers.  And why use the inverse? That seems like more work (likely even the step of  computing the inverse is more work than other methods for the OP).

Comment: Yes, I was *verifying* it rather than *discovering* it; I didn't see that $15^2\equiv-32\pmod{257}$, so the arithmetic was easier for me this way

Answer (score -1):

Elementary theory in modular arithmetic says that $x^p-x\equiv0\mod p$ for any prime $p$. In this case, we have $15^{257}-15\equiv0\mod257$ so $15^{256}\equiv1\mod257$. The order of $15$ then, is a divisor of $256=2^8$. So it must be one of the numbers $1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256$.